# Compress select PDF-Files with Python - Reduce the Size

Tags: python, pdf, compression, reduce, image-compression

It is about the following: I want to develop a tool where you click on a button "**Browse**", a Win Explorer window opens and there you can select a PDF file. After this is done, you click on "**Compress now**" and the file size is then automatically reduced so that you can send the PDF file, for example, via E-Mail (possibly also PDF files with images -> the quality of the images can also be degraded). Is there a way to implement such a tool with Python? If so how? Is there a specific module for it?

I have already started to program the tool so that now I can click on "Browse" and select a PDF file, now I have to go to the compressing part. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutelly YES.

1. To do that you will need a gui library as tkinter or PyQt5(there are more).
2. For manipulations of pdf like splitting or merging pdfminer or PyPDF2.
3. As for ziping there is a non-third party library like zipfile where you can zip files.
4. Then to make it a real app you can use cx_freeze or pyinstaller to make an exe!

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. 
I have already done points 3 and 4, so that won't be a problem. Regarding point 1, what exactly is a Gui library?  Are these modules that you can install with e.g. pip install tkinter?

And regarding point 2, with such pdf manupulating programs you can only merge, encrypt, extract or split files, but not compress them...

Sorry, I know that are quite banal and basic questions, but only in this way I understand the topic correctly.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes you can just pip install PyQt5 , tkinter is already installed in your python.These libraries will create a User Interface with buttons or system interface to e.g. select a file.For the ziping ,zips in pratical is a math problem(algorithm) and if you want do dive more you will need to make a lot of research